How to Add Custom customer Attributes in Account Page?
After adding a custom customer attribute with a dropdown, having values 'A (11)' and 'B (12)', I attempted to display the attributes on the customer account page. However, upon adding the following code to the 'info.phtml' file, I received values instead of names.
https://prnt.sc/UE6AIMR5uiZj
<?php     
 $customAttribute = $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('customer_name');
 if ($customAttribute) {
      echo $block->escapeHtml($customAttribute->getValue());
 }
?>


Are you got the proper value for the custom attribute?

Which type of attribute, you have created?

Drop down multi select

Yes, proper value

Please use the code provided below to display custom attributes on the frontend dashboard.
 <?php
            $customer = $block->getCustomer();
            if ($customer) {
                $customerNameAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_name');
                if ($customerNameAttribute) {
                    $customerNameValue = $customerNameAttribute->getValue();
                    $mappedText = ''; 
                    switch ($customerNameValue) {
                        case '11':
                            $mappedText = __('Car');
                            break;
                        case '10':
                            $mappedText = __('Bus');
                            break;
                        default:
                            $mappedText = __('Unknown');
                            break;
                    }
            ?>
                    <div class="">
                        <strong class="">
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Types : ')) ?></span>
                        </strong>
                        
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($mappedText) ?>
                        
                    </div>
            <?php
                }
            }
            ?>

